# Does the set of eigenvectors of a matrix always span the space?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, orthogonality

I understand that invertible matrices of dimension n have n (complex) eigenvectors.  I'm curious if those eigenvectors always span $C^n$. I think that they do.

The next question is: assuming that the eigenvectors span $C^n$, is there always a way to orthogonalize the eigenvectors? I figure that orthongonalizing them moves them, so they will be knocked off their original spans, and thus will no longer be eigenvectors.  Because of this, it seems to me that having a set of eigenvectors that are also orthogonal is rare.

I'm curious if this is part of why Fourier Analysis and differentiation/integration work so well...  differentiation/integration have a set of eigenfunctions (sines and cosines) that are have both key properties: spanning, and orthogonality.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your first question is no. Take
$$\left (\begin{matrix}
1 & 1\\
0 &1
\end{matrix}\right)$$
It has 1 as the only eigenvalue. If it had a basis of eigenvectors, then it would be the identity matrix.

Orthogonalizing eigenvectors isn't always possible. For instance
$$\left (\begin{matrix}
1 & 1\\
0 &2
\end{matrix}\right)$$ has 2 eigenvectors $(1,1)^T$ and $(1, 0)^T$. If you try to orthogonalize them (e.g. via Gram-Schmidt), you end up mixing the dilation factors provided by the eigenvalues. Thus you lose the eigenvector property. You are correct in saying that orthogonal eigenvectors are a rare thing.

Answer (score 2):

For a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$, the operators $T \in L(V)$ that have $n$ orthonormal eigenvectors are the self-adjoint operators, i.e. operators $T$ such that $T^*=T$. These are the operators that are represented by a symmetric matrix in any orthonormal basis.

If $V$ is complex, then the operators that have $n$ orthonormal eigenvectors are the normal operators, which are operators such that $T^*T=TT^*$.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial has no repeated factors. That tells you that the general matrix does not have a basis of eigenvectors. In one of the examples given above,
$$
            A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right],
$$
the minimal polynomial is $p(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^2$. That tells you that $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Fourier Analysis works so well because the Fourier expansions are obtained from a self-adjoint operator. Self-adjoint operators $A$ have the property that $(A-\lambda I)^nf=0$ iff $(A-\lambda I)f=0$. So counter-examples such as the $A$ above do not exist for self-adjoint operators. In addition to this, eigenfunctions $f,g$ of a self-adjoint operator corresponding to different eigenvalues are automatically orthogonal. Orthogonality plays a role in establishing completeness of eigenfunction expansions.